# LINQ get 10 objects based on integer in object row

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm trying to select 10 users from the database, sorted by a field "points" and its value. The user with the most points can be anywhere in the database, so I'l have to check all point rows, and select those with the highest "Point" integer. The type of the field is a nullable int.

**I have tried :**

```
var top = (from UserInformation in dbConn.UserInformations 
           orderby UserInformation.Points.Count() descending
           select UserInformation).Take(10);
```

But I cant do it this way, because `.Count()` is not valid on `int? (nullable)`, so I tough about using `.getValueOrDefault()` but it wont let me use that one either. So I'm a bit stuck at the moment.

Comment: Can't you simply `orderby UserInformation.Points` ?

Comment: You don't need .Count(). Points isn't a collection. Remove Count()

Comment: Hah, simply and neat. Thanks guys! How do I mark a comment as an answer?

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply remove the `Count()` as `Points` is not a collection and you can order by a `Nullable<int>`.

```
var top = (from UserInformation in dbConn.UserInformations 
           orderby UserInformation.Points descending
           select UserInformation).Take(10);
```